# what $A$ makes $X$ in $\dot{X}=-AX$ converge?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

Suppose that $X,A$ are all $n\times n$ matrix, $X$ is variable and $A$ is constant. We have a differential equation $\dot{X}=-AX$, then my question: what conditions should $A$ satisfies to make $X$ converge to $0_{n\times n}$? What are the related theories?

Thanks.

Comment: I think these lecture notes would be helpful for you: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsDE.aspx

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation#Stability_and_steady_state_of_the_matrix_system

Comment: @Studenttea thanks. I read these pages, and find the X are all vectors. If X is a matrix n×n, does it also work?

Comment: @oks thanks. I read these pages, and find the X are all vectors. If X is a matrix n×n, does it also work?

Comment: Yes, because the matrix X can be treated as n separate n x 1 vectors

Comment: @oks ah yes, thank you vry much.